# How build menu search without no space?

Tags: php, sql, search, opencart

I have problem using open cart. I want to make the Search for menu, example : data is "Hp Xyz 2" when i try input "HpXyz2" the result is 0, and must be exact "Hp Xyz 2" for got result is 1, can some one help me?
sorry , but please can you coordinate what and where should be replaced ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you search in OpenCart, the whole search string goes into SQL.
So according the SQL wildcards:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp
you can use **%** before and after the string or use **_** inside the string like:
**Hp_Xyz_2**

Comment: if you mean it uses %LIKE%, it's not working if user input HPXyz2, well if user input HP_Xyz_2 sure it's work, but that's not what i mean, any suggestion?

Comment: I have no other suggestion on this.